# How can I know the serial port of the device of outside (UART)? Not USB

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-4, sensor, uart

I want to ask. How do I know the serial port of the external UART from Raspberry Pi.

This is a sensor. I connected the wire to the Raspberry Pi. But I can't find which is activate port.

I searched from Google, But almost USB to UART.

If I found the connected port, I want to sent the instruction to test device.

Thx

[image]

Comment: The default port on Raspbian / RPiOS is normally /dev/serial0 (that's a zero at the end).https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md

Comment: Do not forget to enable it and disable console output in raspi-config.  Also remember the Pi is a 3.3v device on the serial port